# Autohide "Drop Down Terminal" from the side

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have the GNOME extension [Drop Down Terminal](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/) to show a terminal from the top after a shortcut keypress. However I prefer it to show from the right hand side instead of from the top. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the position of the terminal, first run

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

A window should appear which lists all the installed GNOME shell extensions. Click the cogwheel (or something similar) icon next to the "Drop Down Terminal" entry. A preferences window should pop up. Select "*Right*" for *Position*.

[image]

You may have to re-login to see the change.